# Type Signature Mismatch on Bifunctor instance definition

Tags: haskell, types, bifunctor

I'm learning about Haskell by working through the book [Haskell Programming from First Principles, Allen & Moronuki](http://haskellbook.com/).

In the exercises for the chapter on Monad Transformers, Functor & Applicative composition, it asks the reader to write Bifunctor instance for the following type

```
data SemiDrei a b c = SemiDrei a
```

My first attempt (which compiles) was

```
instance Bifunctor (SemiDrei a) where
    bimap f g (SemiDrei a) = SemiDrei a
```

But, looking at it, It seemed to me that I ought to be able to write `bimap f g = id` because the last argument is yielded unchanged or write `bimap f g x = x`. Both gave me compile errors, and I'm hoping someone can explain to me why I can't express the `bimap` with these shorter alternatives, i.e. why do I have to specify `(SemiDrei a)`.

I ran this on Haskell 8.6.5 (in case that is relevant)

*attempt: id*

```
instance Bifunctor (SemiDrei a) where
    bimap f g = id

-- compile error message:
• Couldn't match type ‘a1’ with ‘b’
  ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      bimap :: forall a1 b c d.
               (a1 -> b) -> (c -> d) -> SemiDrei a a1 c -> SemiDrei a b d
    at src/Main.hs:69:5-9
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      bimap :: forall a1 b c d.
               (a1 -> b) -> (c -> d) -> SemiDrei a a1 c -> SemiDrei a b d
    at src/Main.hs:69:5-9
  Expected type: SemiDrei a a1 c -> SemiDrei a b d
    Actual type: SemiDrei a b d -> SemiDrei a b d
• In the expression: id
  In an equation for ‘bimap’: bimap f g = id
  In the instance declaration for ‘Bifunctor (SemiDrei a)’
• Relevant bindings include
    f :: a1 -> b (bound at src/Main.hs:69:11)
    bimap :: (a1 -> b) -> (c -> d) -> SemiDrei a a1 c -> SemiDrei a b d
      (bound at src/Main.hs:69:5)
   |
69 |     bimap f g = id
   |                 ^^
```

*attempt: f g x = x*

```
instance Bifunctor (SemiDrei a) where
    bimap f g x = x

-- compile error message:
• Couldn't match type ‘a1’ with ‘b’
  ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      bimap :: forall a1 b c d.
               (a1 -> b) -> (c -> d) -> SemiDrei a a1 c -> SemiDrei a b d
    at src/Main.hs:69:5-9
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      bimap :: forall a1 b c d.
               (a1 -> b) -> (c -> d) -> SemiDrei a a1 c -> SemiDrei a b d
    at src/Main.hs:69:5-9
  Expected type: SemiDrei a b d
    Actual type: SemiDrei a a1 c
• In the expression: x
  In an equation for ‘bimap’: bimap f g x = x
  In the instance declaration for ‘Bifunctor (SemiDrei a)’
• Relevant bindings include
    x :: SemiDrei a a1 c (bound at src/Main.hs:69:15)
    f :: a1 -> b (bound at src/Main.hs:69:11)
    bimap :: (a1 -> b) -> (c -> d) -> SemiDrei a a1 c -> SemiDrei a b d
      (bound at src/Main.hs:69:5)
   |
69 |     bimap f g x = x
   |                   ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There last argument is not, in fact, yielded unchanged: its type changes. The input is `SemiDrei a x y` and the output is `SemiDrei a p q`, where `f :: x -> p` and `g :: y -> q`.

This means that you have to deconstruct the value of the original type and reconstruct a value of the new type, which is what you're doing in the original implementation.

But your intuition is correct: the two values do have the same in-memory representation. And GHC can deduce this fact, and when it does, it will automatically solve a [`Coercible`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.11/base-4.12.0.0/Data-Coerce.html#t:Coercible) constraint for you, which means that you can use the `coerce` function to convert one to the other:

```
 bimap _ _ = coerce
```

Answer (score 6):

This shows the same issue in a simpler case:

```
data T a = K

foo :: T a -> T b
foo K = K  -- type checks

bar :: T a -> T b
bar x = x  -- type error

-- bar = id would also be a type error, for the same reason
```

The issue here is that the two `K` in `foo` values hide their type parameters. A more precise definition would be

```
-- pseudo code
foo (K @a) = K @b
```

Here you can see that the implicit type argument changes. GHC automatically infers those type arguments for us when we write `K` in the definition of `foo`. 
Since they are implicit, they *look* as if they are the same `K`s, but they are not to the type checker.

Instead, when we use `x` in the definition of `bar`, there are no implicit type arguments to infer. We have that `x :: T a` and that's all. We can not use `x` and claim that has a different type `T b`.

Finally, note that using "safe coercions" we can perform the intuitively correct kind-of-`id` which turns one `K` (in one type) into the other `K` of the other type:

```
import Data.Coerce

baz :: T a -> T b
baz = coerce
```

Whether this is better is arguable. For simple cases, pattern matching can be easier to understand than `coerce`, since the latter can perform a vast array of (safe) coercions, possibly leaving the reader to guess about what's actually happening at the type level.

Answer (score 3):

The key to this is in the type signature of `bimap`:

```
bimap :: Bifunctor p => (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
```

In this particular case, if we specialise `p` to `SemiDrei a` and rename the type variables to avoid confusion with that `a`, we get:

```
bimap :: (b -> c) -> (d -> e) -> SemiDrei a b d -> SemiDrei a c e
```

So when you attempt to implement this:

```
bimap f g = ...
```

The functions `f` and `g` are completely arbitrary, not just in their implementation, but in their input and return types as well. `f` has type `b -> c` where `b` and `c` could be absolutely anything - similarly for `g`. The definition you give has to work for absolutely any types and functions that the caller provides - this is what being (parametrically) polymorphic means.

If we now look at your three definitions in these terms, we can solve the apparent mystery:

First:

```
bimap f g (SemiDrei a) = SemiDrei a
```

this is completely fine, as you saw. `SemiDrei a` has type `SemiDrei a b c`, where only `a` is specified. That means it can take on any type such as `SemiDrei a Int String`, or `SemiDrei [Bool] (Char, [Double])`, or whatever. `SemiDrei a` is itself polymorphic, it can be of any compatible type. This means that in particular it can act as both the `SemiDrei a b c` and the `SemiDrei a c e` in the above signature of `bimap`.

Contrast with your other attempts:

```
bimap f g = id
```

The problem here is that `id`, although polymorphic, is not polymorphic *enough* for this purpose. Its type is `a -> a` (for any `a`), which in particular can be specialised to `SemiDrei a b c -> SemiDrei a b c`. But it can't possibly be specialised to a type `SemiDrei a b d -> SemiDrei a c e` as required, because `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` will in general be completely different types. Recall that the *caller* of `bimap` gets to choose what the types are - they can easily choose functions `f` and `g` where `b` and `c` are different types, for example, and then there is no way `id` can take a `SemiDrei a b d` to `SemiDrei a c e`, because they're different types.

At this stage you may object that the value `SemiDrei a` can be a value of all such types. That's perfectly true, but it's not relevant for type inference - the compiler only cares about the types, not what values may inhabit them. It has to consider that different types have completely different, non-intersecting, values. And, say, `SemiDrei a Int String` and `SemiDrei a Bool Char` are in fact different types. Again, the compiler doesn't know that the `Int` etc aren't actually used by any of the values of the type. That's indeed exactly why such "phantom types" (types which appear in a type definition but not in any of their data constructors) are used in practice - to allow the compiler to be able to differentiate them by type, even though the run-time representation might be completely equivalent.

As for your third attempt, `bimap f g x = x`, that's exactly the same as the previous one - it constrains `bimap f g` to have its output type the same as its input. (It's in fact totally equivalent to `bimap f g = id`.)

So the important takeaway is that, at the type-checking phase, the compiler only cares about types - and two types with different names are (and have to be) considered totally distinct, even though it may be that equivalent values can be embedded in both.