# What is a Constant functor?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

I am trying to understand **Constant Functor** from the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor website and can not imaging visually.

It would be also good, if someone can show it as a haskell code, what a **Constant Functor** is and for what is good for.

Comment: The constant functor maps every object in the source category to a single object in the destination category.  It maps every morphism to the identity morphism on that single object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A constant functor is a functor whose object function is a constant function. In haskell:

```
newtype Const r a = Const { unConst :: r }

instance Functor (Const r) where
  fmap _ (Const r) = Const r
```

It maps every type `a` to `r` in a sense, and every function of type `a -> b` to the identity function on `r`

It is good for similar things that the `const` function is good for! Passing to higher order functions, etc.

One interesting use case is in the definition of lens based getters.

Comment: what is the `identity function on r`. I can not see it.

Comment: The identity function is `id x = x`. What I'm referring to is the fact that `fmap f (Const r) == id (Const r) == Const r` for all possible pairs of `f` and `r`

Comment: @sara Not quite; the function doesn't change the wrapped value, but it does change the type. If `f :: t1 -> t2` and `v :: Const a t1`, then `fmap f v :: Const a t2`, but `id v :: Const a t1`.

Comment: I choose to adopt the categorical view that "equal up to isomorphism" is quite close enough to equal :p

Comment: Or in haskell land, equal up to safe coercion!

Comment: @sara It's an important point, though, because it explains why you can't simply define `fmap _ = id`. (A question on this point [came up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58494308/1126841) just a few days ago.)

Answer (score 6):

Like with constant functions: a constant functor is any functor that “ignores” its parameter, and furthermore has a trivial `fmap` operation.

In Haskell, what this means is that every value `F a` contains only data that doesn't contain `a` in any way. I.e., it's just *some other fixed type*, say `R`. Clearly, this could be *any* type, so the actual [standard `Const` functor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Const) has this as another parameter:

```
newtype Const r x = Const { getConst :: r }
```

This is a (**Hask**-endo-)functor because it maps any type `x` to another type `Const r x` – which is actually isomorphic to just `r`. And `fmap`ping, which should change only the `x` values within the `Const r x` structure... well, there are none, so nothing is changed.

```
instance Functor (Const r) where
  fmap _ (Const r) = Const r
```

Answer (score 4):

From `Data.Functor.Const`:

```
newtype Const a b = Const { getConst :: a } deriving Show
```

`Const a b` is a type that holds a value of type `a`, but "tagged" with type `b` as well. Given that `Const` has type `Type -> Type -> Type`, it itself is not a functor, but `Const a` is for any given type `a`.

```
instance Functor (Const m) where
    fmap _ (Const v) = Const v
```

No matter what function you apply, it is ignored and the original value is returned, though with a (possibly) new type.

---

As an example, let's create a value involving a `Char`. The argument sets the first type, leaving the second type unconstrained.

```
> v = Const 'c'
> v
Const {getConst = 'c'}
> :t v
v :: Const Char b
```

Mapping a function over `v` constrains the second type to be the return value of that function.

```
> fmap (+1) v
Const {getConst = 'c'}
> :t fmap (+1) v
fmap (+1) v :: Num b => Const Char b
```

Mapping a different function works the same, but constrains the second type in a different way, again consistent with the return value of the function.

```
> fmap (++"foo") v
Const {getConst = 'c'}
> :t fmap (++"foo") v
fmap (++"foo") v :: Const Char [Char]
```